# keep getting this error what is the proper syntax fornConditionType 'NUMBER_BETWEEN' requires exactly two ConditionValues, but 1 value was supplied

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, conditional-formatting

I am trying to use the conditional filter to check a range between two numbers using google sheets api I keep getting this syntax error how do I fix it please here is my code:

```
 const addFilterViewRequest = [
    {
       'addFilterView' : {
         filter : {
           title : 'PO_Log Precentage',
           range : {
             sheetId : 1701531392,
             'startRowIndex': 1,
             'startColumnIndex':1
             
           },
            'criteria': {
              19:{
               'condition': {

                 'type': 'NUMBER_BETWEEN',
                 'values':[
                   {
                     
                     "userEnteredValue" : "80"
                     
                     
                   }

                 ],
               
               }
               
               
             }
           
         }

       }
    }
    }
  ]
    


  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: addFilterViewRequest },spreadsheet_id);
}
```

Comment: I just want to know how to write the NUMBER_BETWEEN correctly for my spreedsheet.

Comment: Hi, please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. Goodluck 

Answer (score 0):

[ConditionType](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#conditiontype)

> **NUMBER_BETWEEN**
>
> The cell's value must be between the two condition values. Supported by data validation, conditional formatting and filters. Requires exactly two ConditionValues .

```js
                 'values':[
                   {                     
                     "userEnteredValue" : "0"
                   },
                   {                     
                     "userEnteredValue" : "80"
                   }
                 ],
```

Comment: Can you show me how that would look like with my code example I have cause I don't know how to write it properly.

Comment: Added. Please check.

Comment: THANK YOU, I feel so stupid thank you very much